# Is it possible to escape a whole form?

Tags: javascript

Before posting my forms, I serialize them, and before that I escape various fields that need to be escaped.

Is it possible to escape and then serialize the whole form before posting?

Comment: Why escape? serializing will take care of all that. if you escape first, then the serialization will just have to re-escape your escapes and bloat the resulting string even more.

Comment: Why serialize? Doesn't the browser do enough?

Comment: If using jQuery you can do this it will handle the escapes for you. speaking of which since Stackoverflow uses jQuery do this open chrome javascript console(assuming you use chrome) type this and check `$("form").serialize()`

Comment: Well it seems to me that is the only way to submit html data across to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api) has some nice methods for serializing data. Even if you don't want to use the other functionality of the plugin, you can use it to serialize your data.